# Apache hanging for 300 seconds

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

For the past few weeks, our businesses mail server has been intermittently freezing. I've ready through multiple fixes and applied some of them, but I am lost and must ask for help.

Our mail server runs our staff email, (RoundCube and Squirrelmail) and a WordPress install for our Intranet. We are running Ubuntu 10.04, Sendmail, Dovecot, Apache2 and PHP 5.3.2. I have updated all installs to the latest versions that are supported by Ubuntu.

At different times throughout the day, our system CPU use will jump to 100% (of both processors) while monitoring them using HTOP. The output of HTOP always lists these entries as the offending processes, with higher CPU use, of course:

> 5892 www-data  20   0 64404 25092  6816 S  0.0  0.6  0:01.71 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

I am also monitoring Apache using the mod_status module.

I have attached a screenshot of my Server Status page during one of the freezes. The /email entries are RoundCube and the /intranet entries are Wordpress.

[image]

I was hoping someone who has more knowledge of Linux/Apache would be willing to help me out.

Comment: After reading another article, it turns out it may be an issue with Apache caused by Wordpress. If I hold down F5 and refresh the page, Apache locks up the server entirely. I'm still investigating, but at least I'm on the right track finally...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user with uid 976 has a giant email in his sent folder, I suspect his client is repeatedly trying to preview it and bogging down the server. This can happen when it takes longer than a timeout to process the mail.

Have you tried switching to another php worker such as FPM? Last I checked PHP was single threaded execution.

Comment: Thank you. We had a user with 8000 emails in their sent folder!

Comment: Also, I have tried installing MPM_Worker instead of prefork, but have never been able to get it working. When we rebuild our mail server in a few months, I will either use worker, FPM or a different web server altogether.